# Why do I get error when downloading r package from devtools?

Tags: r, devtools

I'm trying to use the Ramf package to analyze root colonization data. I installed the devtools package through `install.packages("devtools")`, and now I'm trying to download the Ramf package through

```
devtools::install_github("mchiapello/Ramf")
```

But when I run the last bit of code, I get an error:

> Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : there is no package called ‘fs’

Does anyone have experience with this error? I'm new to R so I don't know how to fix this.

I'm doing this based on the paper: Ramf: An Open-Source R Package for Statistical Analysis and Display of Quantitative Root Colonization by Arbuscular Mycorrhiza Fungi

link: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/335661759_Ramf_An_Open-Source_R_Package_for_Statistical_Analysis_and_Display_of_Quantitative_Root_Colonization_by_Arbuscular_Mycorrhiza_Fungi

Comment: Try `install.packages("fs")`

Comment: In general, almost every question on SO having to do with failed package installations are due to one of three things: (1) Windows, do not have Rtools installed and compilation is necessary; (2) MacOS, `xcode` is not installed or is out of date; (3) no internet access or the firewall/proxy configuration is incorrect; and this is likely the most common, (4) a dependency package is not available or *its* installation failed. This fourth one is evident by *"no package called 'fs'"*; it's not a problematic error, more of an indicative error. This is simple to resolve: install what's not found.